# Why is font not set to Anonymous Pro?

Tags: emacs, fonts

The only thing in my `.emacs` file is this:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(column-number-mode t)
 '(display-time-mode t)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(load-home-init-file t t)
 '(size-indication-mode t))
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#323232" :foreground "#BBBBBB" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 120 :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "Anonymous Pro")))))
```

and I have copied all the `*.ttf` files to `~/.fonts`, but when I do `M-x describe-font` I get:

```
name (opened by): -adobe-utopia-regular-r-normal--12-120-75-75-p-67-iso8859-1
       full name: -adobe-utopia-regular-r-normal--12-120-75-75-p-67-iso8859-1
            size: 12
          height: 13
 baseline-offset:  0
relative-compose:  0
```

Same thing happens with most other fonts.  Using emacs 23.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running `24.0.93.1` and the configuration above does indeed not work as intended (I replaced "Anonymous Pro" with "Consolas", a font I know works, and it defaults to the system fixed-width font, "DejaVu").

When I replaced `:background "#323232" :foreground "#BBBBBB"` with `:background "white" :foreground "black"` and it worked just fine. Unfortunately that's a far as I've got...

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar behaviour in Emacs 24, but I can get the correct font by adding the following to my Emacs init file:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :foundry "apple" :family "Anonymous_Pro" :height 140)
```

That's on my Mac, so you might want to try either omitting the `:foundry` option or setting it to `nil` or `"unknown"`. Also, it looks like you'll probably want a space in place of the underscore in the font name.